# C# Function to return json , unexpected error

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I have a c# function

```
 public JObject MessageJSON(string dv, string sip)
            {

                JArray details = new JArray();

                //Gr 1
                JArray detail = new JArray();

                JObject detailR = new JObject();
                detailR["dt"] = "int";
                detailR["dn"] = "status";
                detailR["dv"] = dv;

                detail.Add(detailR);

                //Gr 2
                JObject issuerobj = new JObject();
                issuerobj.Add("sid", "2");
                issuerobj.Add("sip", sip);
                issuerobj.Add("storeid", 9999);
                issuerobj.Add("timestamp", 1390236777);


                //list of events

                JObject objectJS = new JObject();
                objectJS.Add(detail);
                objectJS.Add(issuerobj);


                JArray ret = new JArray();
                ret.Add(objectJS);

                JObject stringJSON = new JObject();
                stringJSON.Add(ret);

                return stringJSON;

            }
```

and I need from function to return a JSON like this:

```
{ "events" : [ { "event" : { "details" : [ { "dn" : "status",
                  "dt" : "int",
                  "dv" : 2
                } ],
            "issuer" : { "sid" : 2,
                "sip" : "192.168.1.125",
                "storeid" : 9999,
                "timestamp" : 1390236777
              },
            "type" : "VRA3.5_SCREEN"
          } } ] }
```

One of the problem is that I have error when I try to add list to object.

Advanced thanks

Comment: Which error on what line...

Comment: Can not add Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.  at line no.27

Comment: Better edit your question with that info, nobody likes to count line numbers (eg. put comment on the line where the exception is happening)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
objectJS.Add(detail);
objectJS.Add(issuerobj);
```

To

```
objectJs["details"] = detail;
objectJs["issuer"] = issuerobj;
```

and `stringJSON.Add(ret)` to `stringJSON["events"] = ret`

Comment: Not yet. at the line "objectJS.Add(detail);" will broke my code